# JavaScript menu hides when scrolling down, appears when stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu which is a normal block-displayed div, beacuse there's another div with annotation above. I want the menu to stick to the top as fixed when scrolling down, but immediately hide it. This is because when the user stops scrolling, it appears and when the user srolls up, it hides again, when stop - appears, when scrolldown - hides etc... and always appears when no scrolling.

Could anyone help me?

Here's code of my menu:

```
<div class="menu">
      <div class="menu_tab">
      <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="obsah">
                <div class="kolonky" id="strana">
                     <a href="./"><div class="logo"></div></a>
                </div>
                <div class="kolonky" id="stred">
                    <div class="rozbalit"><a href="obchod.php" id="srdce">Obchod</a>
                        <nav>
                            <a href="priprava_navod.php">Jak připravit matcha čaj</a>
                            <a href="jakaje.php">Jak vychutnat matcha čaj</a>
                            <a href="recepty.php">recepty</a>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rozbalit"><a href="poznejte.php">poznejte matcha</a>
                        <nav>
                <a href="priprava_navod.php">Jak připravit matcha čaj</a>
                <a href="jakaje.php">Jak vychutnat matcha čaj</a>
                <a href="recepty.php">recepty</a>
              </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div class="rozbalit"><a href="priprava_navod.php">příprava</a>
                        <nav>
                <a href="priprava_navod.php">Jak připravit matcha čaj</a>
                <a href="jakaje.php">Jak vychutnat matcha čaj</a>
                <a href="recepty.php">recepty</a>
              </nav>
                    </div>
                    <a href="clanek.php">blog</a>
                    <a href="pribeh.php">o nás</a>
                </div>
                <div class="kolonky" id="strana">
                    <div id="uzivatel">
                        <a href="ucet.php" id="prihlaseni_otevri">Jaroslava B</a>
                        <nav class="uziv_info">
                            <a href="ucet.php">Moje objednávky</a>
                            <a href="ucet.php">Moje adresy</a>
                            <a href="ucet.php">nákupní košík</a>
                            <a href="#">odhlásit</a>
                            <a href="#">nastavení</a>
                        </nav>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><div class="kosik">
                    <span>15</span>
                </div></a>
                <span id="jazyky">CZ</span>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


.hidden_scr{
    display: none !important;
}

.menu{
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.menu.cloned{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    z-index: 5;
}

.menu_tab{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background: transparent;
}

.menu_wr{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.menu_wr.grey{
    background: #edecf0;
}

.menu.grey.cloned{
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.menu .obsah{
    display: table-row;
}

$('.menu').addClass('original').clone().insertAfter('.menu').addClass('cloned').css('position','fixed').css('top','0').css('margin-top','0').css('z-index','3').removeClass('original').hide();

scrollIntervalID = setInterval(stickIt, 10);


function stickIt() {

  var orgElementPos = $('.original').offset();
  orgElementTop = orgElementPos.top;               

  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (orgElementTop)) {    
    orgElement = $('.original');
    coordsOrgElement = orgElement.offset();
    leftOrgElement = coordsOrgElement.left;  
    widthOrgElement = orgElement.css('width');
    $('.cloned').css('left',leftOrgElement+'px').css('top',0).css('width',widthOrgElement).show();
    $('.original').css('visibility','hidden');
  } else {
    $('.cloned').hide();
    $('.original').css('visibility','visible');
  }
} 


var lastScrollTop = 0;
// element should be replaced with the actual target element on which you have applied scroll, use window in case of no target element.
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){ // or window.addEventListener("scroll"....
   var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Credits: "https://github.com/qeremy/so/blob/master/so.dom.js#L426"
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
       $('.menu.cloned').addClass("hidden_scr");
   } else {
      $('.menu.cloned').removeClass("hidden_scr");   
   }
   lastScrollTop = st;
}, false);
```

Comment: Don't change your title with the suffix *Solved*, instead [Accept your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Done :)

```
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.menu').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});
setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }else{
      $('.menu').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down'); 
    }
}, 250);
function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        $('.menu').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
           $('.menu').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;

    if(document.body.scrollTop === 0){
      $(".nav-up").css("background", "transparent");
      $(".nav-down").css("background", "transparent");
    }else{
      $(".nav-up").css("background", "rgba(255,255,255,0.9)");
      $(".nav-down").css("background", "rgba(255,255,255,0.9)");
    }
}
```